# SqliteConnection Xamarin forms Exception Unhandled?

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.forms

When i try to run the project, i am getting this kind of error: "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

pointing in this code:
sqliteconnection = DependencyService.Get().GetConnection();

This is my Class for DB actions:

```
namespace DevoApp.DevoAppFinal.Helpers
{
    public class DatabaseHelper
    {
        static SQLiteConnection sqliteconnection;
        public const string DbFileName = "Devotion.db";

        public DatabaseHelper()
        {
            sqliteconnection = DependencyService.Get<ISQLite>().GetConnection();
            sqliteconnection.CreateTable<Devotion>();
        }

        // Get All Contact data    
        public List<Devotion> GetAllDevotionsData()
        {
            return (from data in sqliteconnection.Table<Devotion>() select data).ToList();
        }

        //Get Specific Contact data
        public Devotion GetDevotionData(int id)
        {
            return sqliteconnection.Table<Devotion>().FirstOrDefault(t => t.devotionalId == id);
        }

        // Delete all Contacts Data
        public void DeleteAllDevotions()
        {
            sqliteconnection.DeleteAll<Devotion>();
        }

        // Delete Specific Contact
        public void DeleteDevotion(int id)
        {
            sqliteconnection.Delete<Devotion>(id);
        }

        // Insert new Contact to DB 
        public void InsertDevotion(Devotion contact)
        {
            sqliteconnection.Insert(contact);
        }

        // Update Contact Data
        public void UpdateDevotion(Devotion contact)
        {
            sqliteconnection.Update(contact);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using the DependencyService, you have to implement the interface in each targeted platform project.

In this case, you should have the ISQLite interface implemented on the platforms you're targeting, i.e. iOS and Android.

To make Xamarin find it at runtime, you will have to register the implementation with the `Dependency` attribute above the namespace. Observe the following example based on a few assumptions of your project.

In your shared library you have declared the interface:

```
public interface ISQLite
{
    // Members here
}
```

Nothing fancy going on there. Then for each platform, you want to run the app on, do something like this:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency (typeof (SQLiteImplementation_iOS))]
namespace DevoApp.DevoAppFinal.iOS
{
    public class SQLiteImplementation_iOS : ISQLite
    {
        // ... Your code
    }
}
```

From the error, it looks like you forgot to add the attribute

Comment: thank you sir. done placing the dependency but same problem occurs.

Comment: [assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(SQLiteDb))]
namespace DevoApp.Droid.Persistence{}